# How can I debug the name of any button pressed with the Unity New Input System?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When using the new input system, some build targets such as andoid can shuffle the names of controller inputs, messing up the bindings.

How can I listen to all inputs and print the name of the button pressed at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Solution adapted from [this form answer](https://forum.unity.com/posts/6647053/) (which no longer works).

You want to create an [input binding](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/ActionBindings.html) at runtime wich matches all button inputs, using an [`InputControlPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputControlPath.html), which provides a "*regular-expression-like*" syntax for creating input bindings.

```cs
var debugAction = new InputAction(binding: "/*/<button>");
```

This particular InputControlPath will match any controler type with `*` and then any button with `<button>`.

We then take this and assign it's `performed` event to a labda which can read the button name from the [`InputControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputControl.html) variable provided by the callback context.

```cs
debugAction.performed += (ctx) => Debug.Log($"Button {ctx.control.name} pressed!");
debugAction.Enable();
```